# How to check for correct MongoDb collection name

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The MongoDb `client.db.collection("collectionName")` method automatically creates the collection if it does not exist, which is great for the first time one accesses it, and not helpful in catching errors in the future.

I was bitten by a spelling error in the collection name, e.g. `client.db.collection("colectionName")`, and want to check the return value before then performing the CRUD action.

It seems as though there are `CollectionOptions` I can pass in, but there is no obvious option that specifies "return null / throw error if collection does not exist", which makes me think I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Declare a variable `const collectionName = 'collectionName'` and use it in your project = no mo typos

Comment: Use `if (db.getCollectionNames().filter( x => x == "collectionName").length > 0)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.